# Why can't I see my globe service in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, web-service, arcglobe, arcgis-explorer

I want to explore it in ArcMap or in ArcExplorer but both cannot "see" it. For the other resources like map services everything is working well.

I can add that the service is started and in a preview view everything seems to be ok.

Comment: Are you talking about ArcGIS Explorer (http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html) or the old ArcExplorer(http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/arcexplorer.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcMap and [ArcExplorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/arcexplorer.html) (not to be confused with [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html)) are 2D clients and cannot consume a globe service. You'll need to [use a 3D client like ArcGlobe or ArcGIS Explorer to use your globe service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Globe_service_usage/009300000n48000000/).

Comment: Of course - you're right. Now in ArcGlobe everything working well. Thank's!

Comment: In ArcGIS Explorer working as well!